# Error when creating events calendar in PHP

Tags: php, calendar

Please be advised, I am newbie in PHP. I don't know what i have to do with **[this calendar script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbhdszzemoffsuf/calendar.zip)**. It's working good when i duplicate the line below manually:

`$cal->addEvent('Event Title', 08, 9, 2013);`

Then i create table for adding events dinamicly. Here my table SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eventcalender` (
  `evt_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `evt_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `evt_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `evt_month` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `evt_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`evt_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I'm using `while()` to display the events

```
   include('config.php');
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `eventcalender` WHERE `evt_year`='".CURRENT_YEAR."' AND `evt_month`='".CURRENT_MONTH_N."'");
    while($s = mysql_fetch_array($get)){

    $titl = $s['evt_title'];
    $tah = substr($s['evt_date'],0,4);
    $har = substr($s['evt_date'],8,2);
    $bul = date('n');

    $cal->addEvent($titl, $har, $bul, $tah);
    }
```

But this not working. what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` [returns indexed array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) but you're using returned array as an associative array.
So, Use:

```
while($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
```

Or

```
while($s = mysql_fetch_array($get,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```